# Spirit Airline Drastically Changed Flight

Tags: air-travel, compensation, spirit-airlines, schedule-change

I had a flight I bought with Spirit Airline direct through them(their website), as direct flight to LAX and back. It's over a month away, but I just received an email from Spirit where they drastically altered it. They pushed it back ~6 hours, and want to do an overnight layover in LAS before doing an early morning flight back home. What options are ahead of me, both for demanding rescheduling and/or compensation. I bought their trip refund policy add-on because of how little faith I had in them so that's always on the table.

Comment: Usually when an airline changes a booking by more than a few minutes they will give you the opportunity to cancel or change your flight for free. Do they not suggest such options in their email?

Comment: They just did something very similar to me. Have never seen this with other airlines.  Seems shady, like they never intended to service the original flight

Answer (score 3):

Spirit's rules are spelled out here: https://content.spirit.com/Shared/en-us/Documents/Contract_of_Carriage.pdf

My read is

1. You are entitled to cancel for a full refund.
2. If you can find an alternative flight on Spirit within 7 days of the original flight, you can ask to be rebooked on that flight for free

> What options are ahead of me, both for demanding ... compensation

There is no compensation beyond the refund of the original fare.

> I bought their trip refund policy add-on

That was probably a mistake. These type of insurance rarely cover anything that the airline doesn't have to pay anyway (without insurance) and there tend to be LOTs of exclusions. If you are worried about not being able to take the trip, you are better of with 3rd party travel insurance.

Sorry, you got what you paid for. Section 8.1 is a particularly fun read

> 8.1 Spirit Airlines Responsibility for Schedules and Operations
> Times shown in a timetable or elsewhere are not guaranteed and form no part of the terms of transportation. Spirit may, without notice, substitute alternate carriers or aircraft, and may alter or omit stopping places shown on the reservation. Schedules are subject to change without notice. Spirit is not responsible or liable for making connections (on its own flights or flights of any other carrier), or for failing to operate any flight according to schedule, or for changing the schedule of any flight.